# DGV Column/CellStyle.format not working

Tags: c#, datagridview

I wanted the user to input values in "dd MMM yyyy" format Only, I'm using `dataGridView1.Columns["Rel_Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd MMM yyyy";` in Form_Load.........

But somehow it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

That 'Format' property is intended for formatting it as output. I'm not sure if you can enforce an inputformat here.

Comment: Ohh I c.... but as u may understand that if a user enteres anything silly, then it will surely be a Prob. So I needed to fix this Input format.

Comment: You can use the Validating event for that. But that happens when the typing is done.